# How I tried to refresh div of the webpage?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net

When I tried to refresh my page I can do it with this code;

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    var interval = 500;
    var refresh = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://localhost:44399/area/areadetail/@ViewBag.i",
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {
                $('.yika').html(html);
                setTimeout(function () {
                    refresh();
                }, interval);
            }
        });
    };
    refresh();
});
```

but my web page seems as;
[image: How my webpage seems as]

How can I fix this situation in my code?

Answer (score 0):

I will refresh the part of the page for you

**step 1.** add this class

```
public class JsonData
{
    public string HtmlMsg { get; set; }
    public string HtmlBody { get; set; }
    public bool Success { get; set; }
}
```

**step 2.** then add class ViewHelper.cs

```
public static class ViewHelper
{
    public static string RenderPartialToString(this ControllerBase controller)
    {
        return RenderViewToString(controller);
    }
    public static string RenderPartialToString(this ControllerBase controller, string partialViewName)
    {
        IView view = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, partialViewName).View;
        return RenderViewToString(controller, view);
    }
    public static string RenderPartialToString(this ControllerBase controller, string partialViewName, object model)
    {
        IView view = ViewEngines.Engines.FindPartialView(controller.ControllerContext, partialViewName).View;
        return RenderViewToString(controller, view, model);
    }
}
```

**step 3.** add your PartialView and Put the part you want to refresh in PartialView exapmle:_MyDiv

```
<div class="col-level1-20">
    <div class="row-new shadow-slider-list background-white border-r-1-ddd border-t-ddd">
    refresh div
    </div>
</div>
```

**step 4.** Your Action in Controller

```
public ActionResult areadetail(int id)
{  
    //............
    return Json(new JsonData()
    {
       HtmlMsg = "OK",
       HtmlBody = this.RenderPartialToString("_MyDiv"),
       Success = true,
    });
}
```

**step 5.** add PartialView in View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "TestPartialView";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}


<section class="row-new margin-t-10">
    <div class="row-new">
        <div class="container style-direction-rtl">
            <span class="style-font-16-sb color-black">Test PartialView</span>
        </div>
        <div class="container style-direction-rtl" id="yika">
             @Html.Partial("_MyDiv")
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

**step 6.** Finally add script

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var interval = 500;
    var refresh = function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://localhost:44399/area/areadetail/@ViewBag.i",
            cache: false,
            success: function (result) {
              if(result.Success)
              {
                 $('#yika').html(result.HtmlBody);
              }
              else  
              {
                alert('failed');
              }
            }
            error: function () {                   
                alert('error');
           }
        });
    };
});
```